# Example of fault tolerance in binary search algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, binary-search

My lecturer gives me this syntax to perform a binary search

```
BS = function(array, x, eps) {
 
  lo <- 1; n <- length(array)

  while (lo <= n) {

    mid <- as.integer(round((lo + n) / 2))

    if (abs(array[mid] - x) <= eps) {

      return(mid)

    } else if (array[mid] < x) { 

      lo <- mid + 1

    } else {

      n <- mid - 1
    }
  }
  return(0)
}
```

while I have a good guess on what the code do, I can't wrap my head around the eps variable, and trying to change it into different value to see what difference it makes doesn't explain it either, can someone please kindly explain what it does?

Answer (score 2):

In this binary search function, `eps` denotes the termination condition. When the following condition is met

```
abs(array[mid] - x) <= eps
```

the code knows that the searching objective `array[mid]` is close to `x` (within the tolerance `eps`), then we return `mid` as the termination of searching.